# Regex to Match String in Multi-Line String

Tags: .net, regex

I have some string in a text file.

```
line con 0
 session-timeout 10 
 exec-timeout 10 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 login authentication console-in
 transport preferred none
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 session-timeout 30 
 exec-timeout 30 0
 logging synchronous
 transport preferred none
 transport input ssh
 transport output ssh
line vty 5 15
 session-timeout 10 
 exec-timeout 10 0
 logging synchronous
 transport preferred none
 transport input ssh
 transport output ssh
```

I'm trying find/match

```
session-timeout 10
exec-timeout 10
```

only under the `line con 0` with Regex.

`line con 0.*\n(.*\n)*.*session-timeout 10.*\n(.*\n)*.*exec-timeout 10` will also catch

```
vty 5 15
 session-timeout 10
 exec-timeout 10
```

Is there a way to do better?

Comment: Is that the entire file? Can you not just get the 2nd and 3rd line?

Comment: This is partial of the configuration file in text format. I'm trying to detect settings with regex

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/tL82pm/1) what is you looking for?

Comment: Thx @Alireza, this still produces false positive if the lines (`session timeout 10, exec-timeout 10`) do not show right after `line con 0` but after `line vty 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 2 lines `session-timeout 10` and `exec-timeout 10` should occur in that order, you can use 2 capture groups.

Per capture group value, make sure that the lines that precede it do not cross matching either `line`  and for example  `session-` for the first match and  `exec-` for the second match using a negative lookahead.

```
^line con 0(?:\r?\n(?!line | session-).*)*\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t]*(session-timeout 10).*(?:\r?\n(?!line| exec-).*)*\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t]*(exec-timeout 10)\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `line con 0` Match literally
- `(?:\r?\n(?!line | session-).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with `line`  or  `session-`
- `\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t]*` Match a newline and optional spaces or tabs
- `(session-timeout 10)` Capture **group 1**, match literally (or use `[0-9]+` to match 1+ digits)
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n(?!line| exec-).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with `line`  or  `exec-`
- `\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t]*` Match a newline and optional spaces or tabs
- `(exec-timeout 10)` Capture **group 2**, match literally
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/AZ98sQ/1) and a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eline+con+0%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!line+%7c+session-%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*%28session-timeout+10%29.*%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!line%7c+exec-%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*%28exec-timeout+10%29%5cb&i=line+con+0%0d%0a+session-timeout+10+%0d%0a+exec-timeout+10+0%0d%0a+privilege+level+15%0d%0a+logging+synchronous%0d%0a+login+authentication+console-in%0d%0a+transport+preferred+none%0d%0a+stopbits+1%0d%0aline+vty+0+4%0d%0a+session-timeout+30+%0d%0a+exec-timeout+30+0%0d%0a+logging+synchronous%0d%0a+transport+preferred+none%0d%0a+transport+input+ssh%0d%0a+transport+output+ssh%0d%0aline+vty+5+15%0d%0a+session-timeout+10+%0d%0a+exec-timeout+10+0%0d%0a+logging+synchronous%0d%0a+transport+preferred+none%0d%0a+transport+input+ssh%0d%0a+transport+output+ssh%0d%0aline+con+0%0d%0a+privilege+level+15%0d%0a+logging+synchronous%0d%0asession-timeout+10+%0d%0a+login+authentication+console-in%0d%0a+transport+preferred+none%0d%0a+stopbits+1%0d%0aexec-timeout+10+0&o=m)*(Click on the "Table" tab to see the groups)*

Comment: Thx @The fourth bird, this works for capturing for the 2 lines just under `con 0`. What would be the best way to write a separate check to capture the same 2 lines under `line vty 0 4` and `line vty 5 15`.

I'm trying to identify settings under different block/identifiers.

Comment: @NormanZhang You could for example match the digits instead of the hard coded values and in the beginning of the pattern match line  followed by a single word and then a digit followed by the rest of the line `^line \w+ [0-9].*` See https://regex101.com/r/obTjYF/1 For exact matches, you have to update the hard coded values in the pattern. See https://regex101.com/r/eyIJ73/1

Comment: thx @The fourth bird, so much your help. I was playing around with https://regex101.com/r/obTjYF/1 but couldn't perform the exact matches for the following pattern. If any lines under `line vty` do not have `session-timeout 10` or `exec-timeout 10`. Looking for pattern does not have the value 10.

Comment: @NormanZhang You might capture the part under line vty where neither session-timeout and exec-timeout have a value of 10 using `^line vty [0-9].*((?:\r?\n(?!line vty [0-9]| (?:session|exec)-timeout 10).*)*)` https://regex101.com/r/Zjs5Pd/1

Comment: thx @The fourth bird again. It does not catch the first `exec-timeout 30` after `line vty 0 4`

https://regex101.com/r/Zjs5Pd/3

Is there a way to match?

Comment: @NormanZhang So you want to capture session and exec timeout, but not if the value is 10. What if 1 of them is 10?

Comment: thx @The fourth bird, I like to capture if either session-timeout !=10 or exec-timeout !=10. If all entries = 10, I'm good. But just different combo of not 10 that I need to catch.

Answer (score 0):

It is because greedy behavior which is the default behavior of regex matching (it tries to expand the match as much as possible while matching the pattern). Adding `?` after quantifiers `+` or `*` solves the problem of greediness.

Therefore use the pattern:

```
line con 0.*?\n(.*?\n)*?.*?session-timeout 10.*?\n(.*?\n)*?.*?exec-timeout 10
```

Which tries to match as few lines as possible.

It matches

```
line con 0
 session-timeout 10 
 exec-timeout 10
```

Comment: `line con 0.*?\n(.*?\n)*?.*?session-timeout 10.*?\n(.*?\n)*?.*?exec-timeout 10`

catches false line (below vty 5) 

```
line con 0
 session-timeout 15 
 exec-timeout 15 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 login authentication console-in
 transport preferred none
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 session-timeout 15 
 exec-timeout 15 0
 logging synchronous
 transport preferred none
 transport input ssh
 transport output ssh
line vty 5 15
 session-timeout 10 
 exec-timeout 10 0
 logging synchronous
 transport preferred none
 transport input ssh
 transport output ssh
```